# Which Markdown library is used?

Tags: discussion

I wonder which markdown library is used in this stackexchange site? In particular I like how it allows LaTeX to be used for Maths. There are many libraries like [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked). Many that knows how to render GitHub Markdown even, or some extended Markdown syntax. But which in particular does things for maths.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SE uses two Markdown processors:

- server-side [Markdownsharp](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/), in C#
- client-side previewer [Pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown), in JavaScript. (Incidentally, I mentioned its history [yesterday](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9642/75064)).

As others mentioned, math rendering is done by MathJax. But the question

> how [Markdown library] allows LaTeX to be used for Maths

is still nontrivial. By itself, Markdown processor does not know anything about MathJax. If it was called *after* MathJax, it would remove all `<span>` tags with formulas, as it removes most HTML tags. If it was called *before* MathJax, it would destroy some TeX formulas by replacing, e.g., the valid formula `$f *g* h$` with `$f <em>g</em> h$`.

The solution implemented on StackExchange is to preprocess user input by a third script (about 130 lines, named `mathjax-editing.js`) which escapes the text within  `$...$` or `$$...$$` from Markdown. This way, formulas go intact through Markdown processing, and eventually get handled by MathJax. For example,  $f *g* h$ renders correctly.

For various reasons, LaTeX formula delimiters `\( \)` and `\[ \]` are not supported by this setup. The most one can do is to type `\\[ \\]` to escape backslashes manually, but this leaves the content of the formula exposed to Markdown processor: for example,
`\\[ f *g* h \\]` becomes \[ f *g* h \]. So much for good LaTeX practice.

Comment: Oh I was wondering if there was some parser that could handle Markdown+MathJax, but looks like its still done separately

Comment: Why would they need a server side processor? They can just store the markdown. Can't they? @75064

Answer (score 3):

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is responsible for the rendering of LaTeX on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

You might also be interested to know that you can right-click on the formatted mathematics to bring up a menu:

[image: MathJax menu]